# iOS change color of tableviewcell and its subview at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiview

I have a `tableviewcell` and  there is another element of type `UIView` (lets call A) in the `taleviewcell` and  want to do the following:

Whenever I click to the `tableviewcell`, its color will change from red to gray and because the A is on the `tableviewcell` its color also should be updated. And whenever it is clicked again, their color must be reversed back from gray to red.

First, I catch the event on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Then I keep the `rowIndex` somewhere to use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and call :

```
self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I check , if `indexPath.row == rowIndex`, then it is the one that i just clicked to change color and I do change its color like:

```
    cell.taskCircularProgressViewOt.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:134.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:134.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

The problem is that, the color of `UIView element (A)` changes slightly after the change done on `tableviewcell`. That is, the color of tableviewcell is changing first, after few milliseconds, its subview of type UIView changes its color.

Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Can't you just set the background colour to `[UIColor clearColor]` and not worry about this?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I implemented your solution, still the same problem.

Comment: It's impossible to have the same problem if you've set `taskCircularProgressViewOt`'s background colour to clear.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I initialized taskCircularProgressViewOt's color in storyboard and changed just taskviewcell's color only, it worked.Thanks

Comment: Post screenshots of the erroneous behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As MacDonald suggested, I initialized taskCircularProgressViewOt's color in storyboard and changed just taskviewcell's color using `[UIColor clearColor]`, it worked.